# Maximum number of images to train a convolutional neural network

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, bigdata

I just wondered if there is a technical limit on the number of images to train a neural network.

I want to work with extremely high numbers of images, around 1,000,000 to 10,000,000 images. Is there a cap because of the graphics card memory? I tried to do some research on that issue, but I mostly find questions about how many images you need to get decent results for a convolutional neural network.

Thanks and best regards,

beinando

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically speaking, there is no limit on how many data points you can use to train *any* neural network. This is true because neural networks that can be trained incrementally and do not need to *"see"* the entire dataset.

Obviously, it helps if your machine is able to store at least a single image and the network in memory.

To train on a large number of images, you will likely need to use batches. This means that each iteration happens on a subset of your data, which can be as small as a single image.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any CAP by any Framework Or technology.

This is how components will be impacted -

**Disc space**

 This will be directly impacted by the total count and size of each image

**Memory**

 This is dependent on your layer's depth, batch size, Kernel count and size of the individual image. Please check SE/Internet on "*RAM needed during CNN learning*"

 It means it will not change much whether image count is 1000 Or 100K if above-mentioned parameters are fixed

**Training time**

 This will depend on your hardware and the level of parallelism but you can't do more than the batch size as backdrop need to reconcile gradients after every batch

**What you must ponder**

 Does your images have so much of variation. Otherwise learning will be stopped after a certain image count.
In case it has got variance across all images, then learning will be very slow. What it means is that **Training time is the only thing you may worry about**